# Confused by "Like" operator in Access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

to my understanding the Like operator used inside queries is intended to perform pattern matching on string fields. I'm very surprised to discover that in Access 2007 it works also on numeric fields. For example, I created a table with a numeric field called Data containing the values 2012,2013,2110 and realized that the following queries do work

```
SELECT myTable.data
FROM myTable
WHERE (((myTable.data) Like "2013"));


SELECT myTable.data
FROM myTable
WHERE (((myTable.data) Like "201*")); 

SELECT myTable.data
FROM myTable
WHERE (((myTable.data) Like 2013)); //this one works even without "
```

Is this the way the Like operator is intended to work ? Does it perform pattern matching on numbers ? I'm confused.

Comment: The numeric value is converted to a string for the comparison.

Comment: This looks like a case of this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/01/30/10495426.aspx

Comment: Ok, I suspected that a conversion, took place, but is this something standard or Access specific ? Problem is that I asked some students on an exam test to choose the correct query for selecting numeric fields different from 2013 and some of them answered --Not like "2013*"-- which I considered wrong :-(

Comment: I don't think it's part of the SQL standard... And you're not the first teacher to be had by this: http://www.itjungle.com/fhg/fhg062211-story01.html - it seems that database vendors are ganging up on you guys, lol!

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
SELECT myTable.data
FROM myTable
WHERE (((myTable.data) Like '201#'));

# Allows you to match on a single numeric digit
* allows you to match any string of any length (including 0 length)
? allows you to match on a single character
```

## [MS-Access Like Operator](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/like2007.php)

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is "Implicit Conversion between Strings and Numeric Data Types" for the LIKE operator to be able to do its job.

A lot of databases systems implement this for other operators like SUBSTR or CONCAT.